# Synonyms of the word "matrix"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Introduction.** A mathematical matrix can be defined as follows:

- "In mathematics, a matrix (plural matrices) is a rectangular array or table of numbers, symbols, or expressions, arranged in rows and columns, which is used to represent a mathematical object or a property of such an object" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics))
- "matrix, a set of numbers arranged in rows and columns so as to form a rectangular array. The numbers are called the elements, or entries, of the matrix."  (https://www.britannica.com/science/matrix-mathematics)
- "a rectangular array (see ARRAY entry 2 sense 5) of mathematical elements (such as the coefficients (see COEFFICIENT sense 1) of simultaneous (see SIMULTANEOUS sense 2) linear equations) that can be combined to form sums and products with similar arrays having an appropriate number of rows and columns" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/matrix)
- "something resembling a mathematical matrix especially in rectangular arrangement of elements into rows and columns" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/matrix)

**Question.** What term we can use as a synonym of "matrix"? Maybe an "arrangement (of elements)"?

**Reasons.** Basically,  I would like to avoid repeating the word "matrix" in a statement similar to this one: "...making the matrix A an orthogonal matrix" (and I do not want to rephrase).

Comment: In mathematics, words are typically given a precise, technical definition.  Trying to make sense of the definitions provided in a non-technical dictionary is likely to fail---get your definitions from the technical documents in which the words are used.  So, first, ignore those dictionary definitions.  They are mostly not useful.  Second, *why*?  Why do you want a synonym for "matrix"?  The whole point of using the term is that it has a precise mathematical definition (or, perhaps, multiple precise definitions, depending on context).  Why do you want *another* word to confuse things?

Comment: @limone Your first 3 definitions use the word “array”. Is there something you don’t like about this option?

Comment: Thanks both for your nice comments! Yes, the word matrix has a well-defined meaning and the usage of other terms might create some confusion or misunderstanding. Also, yes "array" can be used, thanks. In my specific case, I would like to use a synonym for matrix, in a statement similar to this one (adjectives are made up!): 
```The matrix elements are symmetric, non-negative, etc, ...., making the matrix A an orthogonal matrix```. Alternatively, I could use something like this: ```The matrix elements are symmetric, non-negative, etc, ...., making their arrangement an orthogonal matrix```.

Comment: Basically, I do not want to repeat the word matrix here: ```...making the matrix A an orthogonal matrix``` Also, I do not want to rephrase as many would think or suggest... :-)

Comment: @limone First, you should know that what makes mathematical writing good is different from what makes non-technical writing good: repetition in this context is a good thing; as Xander says, using a new word only serves to make things more confusing. For the specific sentence you have in mind, however, you can simply say “making the matrix $A$ orthogonal”.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BenGrossmann! Very helpful! :-)

Comment: "Basically, I do not want to repeat the word matrix here..." Don't do this.  Repetition is not a problem.  If I were to read something like "the matrix $A$ is an orthogonal array", I would be confused.  Is an array the same thing as a matrix?  Did the author choose to use a different word because they are working with some new kind of object?  Or is "array" a synonym of "matrix"?  This is **bad**.  Don't do it.  Technical words have technical meaning, and repetition is not that big a deal.

Comment: If you believe that you are using a word too much, look for other ways to *structure* your writing.  For example, instead of "this makes the matrix $A$ an orthogonal matrix", just write "this makes $A$ an orthogonal matrix."

Comment: Many thanks @XanderHenderson!! Very grateful :-)

Comment: @limone: Please put your statements about *why* you're seeking synonyms into the body of your question. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden. ... Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Blue! Done.. :-)

Comment: "*I would like to avoid repeating the word... making the matrix A an orthogonal matrix*" then say "making the matrix $A$ an orthogonal one".

Comment: Thanks a lot @CroCo!

Answer (score 2):

None of these "definitions" are mathematically precise as a *rectangular array of numbers* is not a well-defined thing. If you do not see this, ask yourself "What is a (oblique) triangular array of numbers?"

We can make this precise in the following way:

> Let $[n]=\{1, 2, \cdots n\}$ be an initial segment of counting numbers.
> Then a matrix of size $m\times n$ with entries in real numbers is just a function $$M : [m]\times[n]\to\mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: That's a definition of a real matrix, though, not a general matrix. "Number" can apply to lots of things, including complex numbers and elements of finite fields.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Exactly. All we need to do is replace $\mathbb{R}$ with whatever the set we need as entries. (Usually, it is a ring. Otherwise, we cannot add or multiply matrices)

Comment: Thanks a lot both @Bumblebee and Thomas Andrews! :-)

Comment: @Bumblebee.. Do you have a reference for the definition you have written?

Comment: @limone: See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/matrix#definition)

Comment: Thanks @Bumblebee!